# Remove in-app-purchase option from iOS app

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store, app-store-connect

I want to submit an iOS app to Apple that doesn't have in-app-purchase enabled.

When I go to iTunes Connect and look at the In App Purchases section for my app I cannot see anywhere where I can remove the in-app-purchase option for my app.

I need to do this because Apple complains when I submit my app that there is no privacy policy and it won't allow submission.

I get the following error message when submitting the app:

"Apps that use the entitlements [com.apple.developer.in-app-payments] must have a privacy policy for [English]. If your app doesn’t use these entitlements, remove them from your app and upload a new binary."

Comment: On submission I get this "Apps that use the entitlements [com.apple.developer.in-app-payments] must have a privacy policy for [English]. If your app doesn’t use these entitlements, remove them from your app and upload a new binary."

Comment: Did you check in developer portal (Member center) if In App Purchase is enabled for app ID of your app?

Comment: Yes it is but can't remove.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In iTunes connect, you need to go to your product and set it to "Remove from Sale". You can then delete it.

Also, In Your Project --> Target --> Capabilities --> Turn In App purchases to off.

> Removing Products from Sale You can choose to stop an In-App Purchase
>   product from being sold in an app. If you do, the In-App Purchase
>   product remains in iTunes Connect.
>
> Important: Removing a product from sale prevents auto-renewable
>   subscriptions from renewing, but it doesn’t keep users from being able
>   to restore products that they purchased previously. bullet
>
> Deleting Products You can delete In-App Purchase products after
>   they’re created, but not if they’re In Review. To delete a product
>   after it is available for sale, you must first remove it from sale.
>
> Important: After you delete an In-App Purchase product, it’s no longer
>   available on iTunes Connect and it can’t be restored. The product ID
>   can’t be reused for another In-App Purchase product.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnectInAppPurchase_Guide/Chapters/WorkingWithYourProductsStatus.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013727-CH33-SW19

Answer (score 1):

This could be related to your App Id identifier setup which together with the iOS certficate is your provisioning profile which you use to sign your app.

If you have created an Explicit App Id ( no wildcard in Bundle Id ) then "Game Center" and "In-App Purchase" services are automatically enabled and cannot be disabled.
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2259/_index.html

> Explicit App IDs are App IDs whose Bundle Identifier portion is a string without the wildcard ("*") character. Furthermore, they are automatically registered for in-app purchase and Game Center...

This can be configured here
https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/identifier/bundle

A Wildcard App ID could be what you need.
You would have to recreate/edit the provisioning profile and sign your app with that.